# Performance issue with spark Dataframe, each iteration takes longer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I´m using **Spark 2.2.1** with **Scala 2.11.12** version as a language to generate a **recursive algorithm**. First, **I tried** an implementation using **RDD** but the time when I used a lot of data was too much. I have made a **new version using DataFrames** but with very little data it takes too much, taking less data in each iteration than in the previous iteration.

**I have tried to cache** variables in different ways (types of persistence included), **to use checkpoints** in different moments, **using the repartition method** with different values ​​and in different functions, and nothing works.

The code starts looking for the minimum distance between the points that make up the matrix (matrix is a DataFrame):

```
println("Finding minimum:")
val minDistRes = matrix.select(min("dist")).first().getFloat(0)
val clusterRes = matrix.where($"dist" === minDistRes)

println(s"New minimum:")
clusterRes.show(1)
```

Then, save the coordenates to the points for later calculations:

```
val point1 = clusterRes.first().getInt(0)
val point2 = clusterRes.first().getInt(1)
```

After, made several filters to use them in the new points generated in the next iteration (the creation of a broadcast variable is necessary to be able to access this data in a later map):

```
matrix = matrix.where("!(idW1 == " + point1 +" and idW2 ==" + point2 + " )").cache()

val dfPoints1 = matrix.where("idW1 == " + point1 + " or idW2 == " + point1).cache()

val dfPoints2 = matrix.where("idW1 == " + point2 + " or idW2 == " + point2).cache()

val dfPoints2Broadcast = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(dfPoints2)

val dfUnionPoints = dfPoints1.union(dfPoints2).cache()

val matrixSub = matrix.except(dfUnionPoints).cache()
```

Continued with the calculation of the new points and I return the matrix that will be used recursively by the algorithm:

```
val newPoints = dfPoints1.map{
          r => val distAux = dfPoints2Broadcast.value.where("idW1 == " + r.getInt(0) + 
         " or idW1 == " + r.getInt(1) + " or idW2 == " + r.getInt(0) + " or idW2 == " + 
         r.getInt(1)).first().getFloat(2)

        (newIndex.toInt, filterDF(r.getInt(0),r.getInt(1), point1, point2), math.min(r.getFloat(2), distAux))
 }.asInstanceOf[Dataset[Row]]

matrix = matrixSub.union(newPoints)
```

Finalize each iteration caching the matrix variable and realized a checkpoint every so often:

```
matrix.cache()

if (a % 5 == 0)
 matrix.checkpoint()
```

Comment: Each iteration takes longer, because with each iteration execution plan gets more complex. `DataFrames` are not designed for general purpose iterative processing. And just out of look of this code  it is at least _O(N^2)_ and brute-forcing problems like this, just won't at scale.